# checkBox action event in uitableviewcell

Tags: ios

I am having custom-cell in which i put the UIButton as the CheckBox.
I want the array of selected checkBox indexPath in ViewController.
I am trying to set the UIButton Action event into the ViewController but it is not accessible. 
 Here is my Code,

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomTableViewCellSaveSearchTableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SaveSearchCell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableViewCellSaveSearchTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [self setText:cell];
    [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.btnDelete.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
-(void)btnClick : (UIButton *)btn
{
    // I Can't accaes this method.
}
```

How can i get this.

Comment: are you calling the btnClick :  method in didSelectrowatIndexpath

Comment: No I am calling it in a Normal way as UIButton in iewController

Comment: That is the wrong way to go. Cells should not contain buttons but be selectable as a whole. If the button is tapped how do you know which in cell it was?

Comment: it's easily get from button click event by getting cell in click event and from the indexPath.row.

Comment: You need to add button to cell like this [cell addsubview btnDelete];

Comment: Just to show if current cell is selected or not, you should use UITableViewAccessoryType, there won't be any requirement for button in cell to handle selection thing. The selection thing could then be easily handled in didSelectRow method of tableView

Comment: i have requirement to set the custom button as checkbox.

Comment: i tried your code and it worked for me. are you sure your btnDelete is connected properly and not nil?

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCells have a state of their own to reflect if they are selected or not. You don't need a button in the cells (it is discouraged for UX reasons anyway). Check [here](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-handle-row-selection-in-uitableview/) for a tutorial.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for Replay. I am already trying as you are providing in link. but my requirement is  to add the custom checkbox through UIButton

Comment: Ok, do you have multiple cells and need to know which in cell it was tapped?

Comment: I am having multiple cell and each of those having custom button as checkBox. and i want to access those checkbox click event in ViewController rather then in Custom cell Class

Answer (score 0):

**Do according to these three floowing method.**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
chekMarkArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
int totalData = 10;
chekMarkArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:totalData];
for (int i=0; i<totalData; i++) {
     [chekMarkArray addObject:@(0)];
}
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UIButton *testButton;
if (cell == nil ||1) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    testButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, 5,25, 25);
    testButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    BOOL selectindex = [[chekMarkArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    if (!selectindex) {
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }else{
        testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }

    [testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(DropDownPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [cell addSubview:testButton];
}

return cell;
}
```

**checked button action**

```
-(void)btnClick : (UIButton *)btn
{
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;
BOOL currentStatus = [[chekMarkArray objectAtIndex:button.tag] boolValue];
//deselect all selection
for (int i=0;i<chekMarkArray.count;i++) {
    [chekMarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@(0)];//comment this line for multiple selected button
}
//select current button
[chekMarkArray replaceObjectAtIndex:button.tag withObject:@(!currentStatus)];
[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: instead of UITableviewcell i have to use CustomCell. is it work for the customCell?

Comment: in that case write -(void)btnClick : (UIButton *)btn method in "CustomTableViewCellSaveSearchTableViewCell" class

Comment: yes i did it. it's work perfect. but i want to store the indexpath.row in NSMutablearray at this click event. and if i do this it's not add object in the array, it's replace object every time in array. so where do i alloc-init the NSMutableArray?

Comment: wait a bit please i am updating

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code instead of button

first Alloc NsmutableArray in ViewDidLoad 
and put an Button outside Tableview to complete your action.

then add

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if(cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
   [selectedRowsArray addObject:[arrShareTickets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [selectedRowsArray removeObject:indexPath];
}
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```